# How to delete the mail from the senders sent item from Outlook

Tags: vba, excel, email, outlook

I am getting run time error for the below Excel to VBA code to delete the senders mail

```
        Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        Dim PriorVal As String
' For the worksheet AuditLog        
        With Sheets("AuditLog")
        If Selection(1).Value = "" Then
                PriorVal = "Blank"
            Else
                PriorVal = Selection(1).Value
            End If
        Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OlObjects = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        Set newmsg = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        'add recipients
        newmsg.Recipients.Add ("add your mail id")
        'add subject
        newmsg.Subject = ("AuditLog has a violator") '"," Environ("UserName"), Environ("ComputerName"), & sh.Name "
        'add body
        newmsg.Body = Application.UserName & " has made changes to the AuditLog _ tab at cell position " & Target(1).Address & ", " & Target(1).Value
        newmsg.Display 'display
        newmsg.Send 'send message
        newmsg.DeleteAfterSubmit = True
        End With
            Set newmsg = Nothing:     Set OutlookApp = Nothing:
        End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

```
newmsg.Send 'send message
newmsg.DeleteAfterSubmit = True
```

switch these around

```
newmsg.DeleteAfterSubmit = True
newmsg.Send 'send message
```

Comment: Hello Mrbungle, I have tried this but still the mail is available under the sent item with one exception. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @mrbungle wrote, as a rule of thumb, once you call Send, the only allowed operation is dereferencing the message  - it now belongs to the spooler.

There is also no reason to call Display (modelessly) and then Send while the message is still being displayed. If you are displaying the message, would you not want the user to click the Send button?

Comment: Hi Dmitry, I want the mail should be send who violates the AuditLog tab, but don't want him to know that there was a mail trigger to his supervisor as the traces will be available under Sent Items.

Comment: Do not call Display, set the DeleteAfterSubmit property to true, call Send.

Comment: I have change the code as suggested and you are right.